How does nginx generate dynamic error pages?
I want to configure a simple and generic error page in Nginx that returns HTTP error codes, and have it referenced in all server {} blocks, like this: include vhost/error.page.
Here’s what I’ve tried:
    error_page 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 421 422 423 424 425 426 428 429 431 451 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 510 511 = @custom_error;

  location @custom_error {
    add_header Content-Type text/html;
    return 200 '

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <html>
      <body>
          <h1>$status</h1>
          <p>Error Code $status</p>
      </body>
  </html>';

    }

However, I noticed that all the error pages just return Error Code 200.
I realized that it might be due to the return 200 directive, so I added set $code $status and changed all the return variables to $code, like this:
  location @custom_error {
    set $code $status;
    add_header Content-Type text/html;
    return 200 '

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <html>
      <body>
          <h1>$code</h1>
          <p>Error Code $code</p>
      </body>
  </html>';

    }

Now, the error page content returns Error Code 000.
How can I fix this and achieve the desired functionality?

Your error_page statement contains an = which changes the status code. Try removing the =.
